# Do you understand this?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Let's say I have several water faucets in my house, but one of them has low water pressure and I say to you:

"I have a water faucet which water is very weak."

Would you understand that I have more water faucets not only one? And also is that sentence correct grammatically speaking? I know I have more choices to imply that such as; "I have a water faucet with low water pressure.", "I have a water faucet whose water pressure is low." and "I have a water faucet wich/that has low water pressure." there might be more options but yesterday I was chatting with my nephew who lives in the U.S. and I texted him that because only that came to my mind when I was chatting with him I wonder if I sounded awkward or if it was ungrammatical. What do you guys think?

Comment: One of my faucets has low pressure.

Comment: @ab2 -  Actually, the pressure is probably fine.  It's the flow rate that is low.

Comment: Whilst not incorrect from my eyes, you said "the water is weak".  In American english we usually are more definitive of exactly what it is that is weak.  We would usually say "I have a faucet with low pressure."

Comment: Thanks for all your comments I know I should have written something with "low pressure" not "weak water"

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with "whose water is weak" but "which" jars me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically asking about your text, not about the various (better) options there are to make your point.

The major problem with the meaning of your text is with **which**. It makes your sentence incorrect grammatically. The proper word is **whose**.

Thus: **I have a water faucet whose pressure is very weak.**

*Which* is a relative pronoun, and *whose* is a possessive.

You're basically saying *the water faucet's pressure is very weak*.

Comment: Actually, it's the rate of flow that's weak.  Likely the pressure is normal.

Comment: Yeah what I tried to imply was that only a little bit of water came out of the faucet due to poor water supplement from the water company.